# PostgreSQL(9.4) Scheduling Agent pgAgent : Couldn't get a connection to the database

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I have been trying to schedule a job using pgAgent. But, I am getting the below error:

> "Couldn't get a connection to the database"

Following are the configurations:

pgAgent Configuration:

[image: pgAgent Configuration]

Scheduled Job Configuration:

[image: Scheduled Job Configuration]

Please help to get it resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I have resolved the issue. I did make the credential entry "**localhost:5432:testing:postgres:*[Enter password]***" in file "**pgpass.conf**" which exist at location "**C:\Users\sys*[service username]*\AppData\Roaming\postgresql**". 
Now it is working perfectly.