# Set Up File Export in pgAgent

Tags: postgresql-11, pgagent

I'm new to pgAgent, and trying to set up a job that will export a file every 5 minutes (just for testing; once I have the syntax down it'll be dispersed to numerous jobs). The below test code works fine when I run it in a query editor, however pgAgent doesn't seem to like it. Any help on what I need to change?

```
DO $$
DECLARE ssql varchar := 'COPY (SELECT * FROM public.users LIMIT 10) TO ''C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgExport' || TO_CHAR(NOW(),'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') || '.csv'' WITH CSV DELIMITER '','' HEADER;';

BEGIN
    EXECUTE ssql;
END; $$
```

I can't find any sort of error as far as what's happening; rather the file just doesn't appear when I run the job manually nor when I let the schedule run.

Answer (score 2):

So it turned out to not be a syntax issue, but rather a permissions issue. Found the answer here ([couldn't get a connection to the database - Postgres Job Scheduling issued (Windows based machine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832732/couldnt-get-a-connection-to-the-database-postgres-job-scheduling-issued-wind/51361900)) if anyone is interested - basically have to set job as a "remote" server (even if running locally) and supply the connection string with localhost.